# How to reset an authentication flow to a specific point in the flow

Tags: keycloak

I have an authentication flow that includes two authenticators:

- CustomPreOtpAuthenticator
- CustomOtpAuthenticator

The first allows the user to choose how to receive the code (sms, email, etc.). The second validates the code. I want to implement a "try again" feature in CustomOtpAuthenticator which navigates back to CustomPreOtpAuthenticator to allow the user to change their mind about how to receive the code and/or change their telephone number (for the sms case). I have the back navigation working via the following code in CustomOtpAuthenticator.action():

```
if (tryAgain) {
    // The auth note with CustomPreOtpAuthenticator execution id was set in CustomPreOtpAuthenticator
    String preAuthId = authSession.getAuthNote(AbOtpConstants.AB_PRE_AUTHENTICATOR_EXECUTION_ID);
    authSession.setExecutionStatus(preAuthId, CommonClientSessionModel.ExecutionStatus.FAILED);
    context.success(); // <--- Problem!
    return;
}
```

The problem is setting the status in CustomOtpAuthenticator. Since the status was set to success, when I then submit the form in CustomPreOtpAuthenticator, CustomOtpAuthenticator's form is not shown because its status is already set. So I somehow need to reset CustomOtpAuthenticator's status.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out a solution which is somewhat of a hack. In CustomOtpAuthentication.authenticate(). I added the following code:

```
String flowId = context.getExecution().getParentFlow();
Stream<AuthenticationExecutionModel> executions =  context.getRealm().getAuthenticationExecutionsStream(flowId);
AuthenticationExecutionModel otpExecution = executions
    .filter(e -> e.getAuthenticator().equals("custom-otp-authenticator"))
    .findFirst()
    .get();

authSession.setExecutionStatus(otpExecution.getId(), CommonClientSessionModel.ExecutionStatus.FAILED);
```

which finds the CustomOtpAuthenticator execution which is next in the flow and sets its status to FAILED. This is a noop the first time through, but resets the status of that execution the second time through. Better solutions would be welcome before I mark this as the solution.